# PHP class property visibility issue

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a number of classes I have written and recently thought I could define a property in a common parent class and have it visible to all child classes, but apparently I seem to be running into some form of a scope issue and cannot determine where I went wrong.

So, my classes are as follows;

```
class AppInit {
  protected $var;
}

class Jobs extends AppInit {
  public function setVar($val) {
    $this->var = $val;
  }
}

class Items extends AppInit {
  public function showVar() {
    echo $this->var;
  }
}

$obj1 = new Jobs();
$obj1->setVar(12345);

$obj2 = new Items();
$obj2->showVar();

# Nothing will print because AppInit->var is only defined within the instance that initiated it.
```

The issue I'm having is that $obj2 seems to have no visibility into the protected property $var that is set at the parent level by the other class instance. How can I make the AppInit->var visible across all instances of AppInit that are created as part of the inheritance?

Thanks folks!

Comment: But they are different instances. Trying to make sure I'm not missing something. You want to `clone` maybe?

Comment: You haven't set it in `$obj2`, you set it in `$obj1`.

Comment: `$obj2` instances `$var` is never set, so it is NULL. There is no problem of visibility.

Comment: That's the issue. I want to initialize it in a single instance and have it available across any other instances. Is that even possible?

Comment: @Skittles yes make it **static** so it will be accessible from all classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With this:

```
class Jobs extends AppInit {
  public function setVar($val) {
    $this->var = $val;
  }
}
```

You are having one instance of `AppInit` instantiated from `Jobs`

Here:

```
class Items extends AppInit {
  public function showVar() {
    echo $this->var;
  }
}
```

You are having **another** instance of `AppInit` instantiated by `Items`.

That is why!

If you want to have `var` same for both `Items` and `Jobs` make it static.

Comment: Setting it to static was the right path! Of course...I needed to update the code to then use parent::$var, but it worked great. Thank you, Venelin!